# Flash Game: All resources do not completely load for different users

Tags: flash, loading, multiplayer

I am running an online flash multiplayer game. However, I have been facing a problem lately where some users cannot actually completely load all the resources required to run the game. The percentage that users get stuck at is different for different users (for instance, one could get stuck at 43% and some other at 91%).

I don't think there is any problem with the files as such because the resources are completely loaded for the majority of the users and the game works just fine for them. Has anyone faced such a problem before? If so, did you manage to find a solution? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
SK

Comment: Need more info [how are resources being loaded, etc]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend, first of all, making sure you have event handlers set up for IOErrorEvent.ERROR for each of the assets you're attempting to load, and I would also suggest you run some function to check that all assets have been loaded before the application advances to its next section.

It may be that your users are accessing the app from a dodgy connection (cafe wifi anybody?). Perhaps their wireless signal intermittently goes out while they browse, and particularly in the middle of your download?